# Receiving "...has already been registered..." from EventLog.CreateEventSource even though I'm checking !EventLog.SourceExists

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, event-log

My following code fails with "...has already been registered as a source on the local computer" even though I'm doing checks first:

```
lock ( eventLock )
{
    string eventLog = Constants.EventLogPL;
    string eventSrc = Constants.EventSrcPL;

    if (!EventLog.Exists(eventLog))
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(eventSrc))
        {
            try
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventSrc, eventLog);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd have thought my call to `!EventLog.SourceExists` would have been enough to prevent my error!
I'm on 2010 .NET 4 and Windows 7 64 compiling to any CPU.

**Edit:** Updated code to get Constant's to locals to check they don't change, and use locking to make sure only one thread can test and create. Code still fails with the same error.

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded application?

Comment: Yes, but I did add code to write out `Constants.EventLogPL` and `Constants.EventSrcPL` before/after each Exists and CreateEventSource, just to check the values hadn't changed. Which they hadn't.

Comment: I've edited my code to store the `Constants` in local variables and used a lock to guard thread issues, same error. I'm even using SysInternals Process Monitor to check what's going on; so far only name not found (expected) and Success - no errors when I step over `EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventSrc, eventLog);` which I would have expected.

Comment: In my case, don't name the source the same as the service, it will throw these errors.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the problem after digging in to [Sysinternals' Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) a little more:

Calling `EventLog.Exists("MyLog");`

Logs Name not found, as expected in:

*KLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\MyLog*

Calling `EventLog.SourceExists("MySource");`

Checks several places, name not found in as expected:

*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\HardwareEvents\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Internet Explorer\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Key Management Service\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Media Center\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\ODiag\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\OSession\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Security\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\System\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\VisualSVNServer\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Windows PowerShell\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\HardwareEvents\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Internet Explorer\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Key Management Service\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Media Center\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\ODiag\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\OSession\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Security\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\System\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\VisualSVNServer\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Windows PowerShell\MySource*
*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\MyLog*

However, calling `EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyLog");`

Finds MyLog in the following registry location and errors:

*HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyLog*

Removing "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyLog" and re-running fixed my problem!

Looks like the `.Exists` don't look in all the places `.CreateEvent` does!

Comment: I second this. Jaroslav Jandek - this is happening in my test env on subsequent runs, so no chance of concurrency. I think this is a side effect of changing the log and/or source names being used after having initially run the code and created the log and source. Seems to get the detection confused.

Comment: OK, actually I think I've worked it out.
Initially, I set up a source with name x and a log with name y. Subsequently, I changed the log to name x and the source to name z. I'm getting the error because the class won't let me register a new eventlog with the same name as an existing eventsource.
To solve the problem, I ran
EventLog.DeleteEventSource(x);
first and once the obsolete source was gone, end of problem.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Had a duplicate entry in "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application" that wasn't showing up in the Eventlog list. Once the duplicate registry entry was deleted, the error went away and the Eventlog was created successfully -Bala

Answer (score 2):

```
//0 for false, 1 for true.
private static int usingResource = 0;

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(Constants.EventSrcPL))
{
    //0 indicates that the method is not in use.
    if (0 == Interlocked.Exchange(ref usingResource, 1))
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(Constants.EventSrcPL))
        {
            try
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(Constants.EventSrcPL, Constants.EventLogPL);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                //Release the lock
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref usingResource, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    usingResource = 0;
}
```

Does not solve the issue when the source is created by a different application in the exact time you are accessing the event log.

**Edited**: made modifications that account for the delayed creation of a `EventSource`.

Comment: I had a breakpoint in my code so wasn't seeing thread issues, but I've added a `lock(...)` to guard the test/create similar to your `Interlocked.Exchange` but I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: @JLWarlow: It takes some time to create the resource. So if you execute the code twice, you may get the exception. I have modified the code to account for the problem.